# Is there a way to target the previous element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a form that gets generated by my CMS. The form gets generated in a table that for the most part has little in the way of ID's or Classes to grab and manipulate things.

Here is an example of the section i'm working with:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="wrappable" id="4354-3-34-2324">
           <span class="explicit">
               "Give me your answer"
           </span>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <span>
            <textarea></textarea>
        </span>
        </br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have a question that shows above this one and based on whether the input for that is yes or no i want to be able to hide/show this bit of code.

The only thing I can think of to hide this question all with one statement is to use the id of the label and then somehow reach up a level to the td and set it's display to none. That way I can easily toggle it's visibility with jQuery based on the response to the question above it.

Does anyone know if this is possible or if there is an easier way I could go about this?

Comment: Only as curiosity: what the hell is `</br>` ??

Comment: You want to get he parent element you mean, which can be doing with `.parent()`.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude my bad, fat fingered the keyboard there! should just be a regular <br/>

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 LOL doesn't matter, I'm curious about that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only thing I can think of to hide this question all with one
>   statement is to use the id of the label and then somehow reach up a
>   level to the td and set it's display to none. That way I can easily
>   toggle it's visibility with jQuery based on the response to the
>   question above it.

If you want the immediate parent of a specific element, you can use the [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) function in jQuery :

```
// This would hide the parent element for your specific element
$('#4354-3-34-2324').parent().hide();
```

If you need to go beyond that, you can use the [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function to traverse up the DOM to find a the nearest element via a selector:

```
// This would hide the closest <td> element for your specific 
$('#4354-3-34-2324').closest('td').hide();
```

Since you want to trigger this based on the result of your question, you could listen to your specific `<textarea>` elements and determine when they change and show / hide accordingly :

```
$(document).on('change','textarea',function(){
     // When a text area has changed, check it's value
     var text = $(this).val();
     // Use the text here to determine how to handle what you need
     if(condition){ 
         // Hide the nearest <td> if your condition is met
         $(this).closest('td').hide();
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! The closest 'td' selection worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Capture the `click` event for the `label` itself

```
$("#4354-3-34-2324").on('click', function(){
   $(this).parent().hide();
});
```